# Getting undefined values in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm trying to get values and insert them in the dropdown. But when I try to do that I get value as undefined instead of proper value. I want to get values from train array and populate dropdown with them. When I get station.name correct value is returned, but when i try to access train.number undefined value is returned.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import StationService from '../services/StationService';

class CreateStationComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            station: {
                id: this.props.match.params.id,
                city: '',
                name: '',
                trains: [
                    {
                        number: '',
                        numberOfCarriages: ''
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

        this.changeCityHandles = this.changeCityHandles.bind(this);
        this.changeNameHandles = this.changeNameHandles.bind(this);
        this.saveStation = this.saveStation.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        if (this.state.station.id === '_add') {
            return;
        } else {
            StationService.getStationById(this.state.station.id).then((res) => {
                let station = res.data;
                this.setState({ name: station.name, city: station.city, number: station.trains.number })
            });
        }
        // console.log(this.state.station.name + 'dfddddd');
    }

    changeCityHandles = (event) => {
        this.setState({ number: this.state.station, trains: event.target.value });
    }

    changeNameHandles = (event) => {
        this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
    }

    saveStation = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let station = { city: this.state.city, name: this.state.name, number: this.state.train.number, numberOfCarriages: this.state.train.numberOfCarriages }

        if (this.state.station.id === '_add') {
            StationService.createStation(station).then(res => {
                this.props.history.push('/stations');
            });
        } else {
            StationService.updateStation(station, this.state.station.id).then(res => {
                this.props.history.push('/stations');
            });
        }
    }

    cancel() {
        this.props.history.push('/stations');
    }

    getTitle() {
        if (this.state.id === '_add') {
            return <h3 className="text-center">Dodaj stację</h3>
        } else {
            return <h3 className="text-center">Modyfikuj stację</h3>
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <form>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <input  name="name" className="form-control" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.changeNameHandles} />
                                </div>

                                    <select>
                                        {this.state.station.trains.map(train => <option key={train.id} value={train.number}>{train.number}</option>)}

                                    </select>
  
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the bug line?

Comment: This value is undefined `{this.state.station.trains.map(train => <option key={train.id} value={train.number}>{train.number}</option>)}`

Comment: Do you get any value when you try to `console.log(this.state.station.trains)`

Comment: @SinanYaman I get `[object Object]`

Comment: Can you try this for debugging purposes:
`<select>
 {this.state.station.trains.map(train => { 
   console.log(train);
   return  <option key={train.id} value={train.number}>{train.number}</option>
})}  </select>` and see if you get any data when you try to log the train object

Comment: @SinanYaman I get response with an empty values

Comment: Well there you go, nothing wrong with the code. You just can't get the data correctly. That is a whole other question.

Comment: @SinanYaman Do you know what might be the problem, because in response I get all the data?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Try this:-
    
        {this.state.station && this.state.station.trains.length && 
 && this.state.station.trains.map((train , i) => {
                return (
                     <React.Fragment>
                            { train && train?.number &&
          <option key={train?.id} value={train?.number}>{train?.number}</option>       
                             }
                     </React.Fragment>
                          );
         })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: There is still no difference. Values are empty

Comment: This can only happen when train.number have some whitespace. Use trim() for that.

Comment: There are not any whitespaces. I guess the problem is somewhere else but I don't know where exactly

Answer (score 1):

It's `trains[0].number` not `trains.number`, because the object you are trying to access is nested in an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
StationService.getStationById(this.state.station.id).then((res) => {
                let station = res.data;
                this.setState({ name: station.name, city: station.city, number: station.trains.number })
            });
```

This code tries to set state variables of name, city and number. Instead try doing this

```
            StationService.getStationById(this.state.station.id).then((res) => {
                let station = res.data;
                this.setState({ station: { 
                     ...state.station,
                     name: station.name,
                     city: station.city,
                     trains: station.trains }
                 })
               });
```

Comment: You could do this.setState({station)} directly but I am assuming you don't want to overwrite the id

Comment: You have the same issue everywhere you `setState`. Please do some work before asking another question, as you know the problem and the solution now. Try on your own and ask another question if there is another issue. Cheers